# How to change Office addin's runtime to use Microsoft edge WebView 2?

Tags: office365, runtime, office-addins, webview2

I want to change the office addin's runtime to use Microsoft Edge WebView2 runtime for **Office 365 Semi annual channel**.

I found an article by Microsoft on how to change office Addin's runtime and use the following steps -> https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blogs/understanding-office-add-ins-runtime/

Unfortunately, it was not successfully. The article stated to change the registry key settings which will change the office addin's runtime. I went to the windows registry to the following hive HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\WEF and then created a DWord key named "Win32WebView2" and set value of 1.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly4Ue.png)

**Environment:**

Windows: Win 10

Office: Office 365 semi annual channel Build 2008 (16.0.13127.21624)

Is there any other way I can change the office addin runtime to use MS edge WebView2 for office 365 semi annual channel? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the Edge web browser installed on the system?

Comment: Yes , ms edge is installed and ms edge webview2 is installed as well

Comment: Did you eventually solve this issue?

Comment: No, but the good news it that the semi annual channel now uses Webview 2 which came with the updates